# Azure Notification hub vs APNS

Tags: ios, azure, notifications, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I have to send push notifications to the specific users from the azure database list on insert of column into table. I am not sure which way I should I use direct APNS or Notifications hub?

1) If i use direct APNS from azure(below insert query), on insert  of column in table TODOITEM I gets the push notification , but `What should i do to send it to specific user from table` I figured out `null` should be replaced with tokens where do I get specific user tokes

```
 function insert(item, user, request) {
request.execute();

setTimeout(function() {
    push.apns.send(null, {
        alert: "Alert: " + item.text,
        payload: {
            inAppMessage: "Hey, a new item arrived: '" + item.text + "'"
        }
    });
}, 2500);}
```

2) If i use the notification hub, I am not even able to use the push notification on insert of column in table which was happening in first case.
in IOS side, I am using code for notification hub:

```
SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:
                          @"..
[hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil completion:^(NSError* error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

How do I send the notification on table insert as it was happening in case 1 and how do i send to specific user of table (is there any way i can query the table and send)

Please can you answer both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tags.  A tag can uniquely identify a device (unique ID) or a group of devices (ex: country, team, etc).

In your iOS code, your currently passing a nil to the tags parameter.  Change that to a unique ID but don't use the device token.  I just lost an entire day figuring out that it's too long but doesn't generate any errors if used as a tag.  Go figure!  I'm using a GUID that I generate each time the app is launched and I store it on the backend.

In your JS code, replace null with the unique ID.  You can specify multiple tags using a string (not an array) separating the tags with commas and no spaces.

In the portal, you can open the Service Hub page and use the debug tab to send a test notification using a tag.

Comment: Thanks!! tht worked.. but Instead of tags anything else is possible .. bcz i have use database .. from database i have pull list of users and then i have to send them notification.. in this case.. how tag would work

Comment: Is that possible to interact with database?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  When your app launches, create an ID and send it to Mobile Services.  Store that ID in the database.  When sending a notification, retrieve the iD and use it as a tag.

Comment: Lets say I have 100s users with different ids to send notification... and list of these user i will get from the database,.. Now I cannot save 100s tags as these user will be different based on query... in this case what should i do.. how do i store tags for them and how do i send notification